# How can I change the button text in Shoes?

Tags: shoes

Once a button is created in Shoes, is it possible to change the text? I've tried modifying the :text key in the button style--@button.style.inspect confirms the text is changed--but the button still shows the original text.

Comment: Put your shoes on.  Then change the button text.  :)

Comment: +1-Hahaha That was hilarious;)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't figured out how to change the text on the existing button.  I suspect it just isn't supported as of yet.  You could create a new button and replace the old one.  Unfortunately, at least on Windows, removing a button mucks up all the click events.  I haven't tried it on another platform, but maybe it'll work.  Try something like this:

```
Shoes.app do
  para 'This is some text.'

  @btn = button 'a' do |btn|
    alert 'Hello, World!'
  end

  para 'Blah blah blah'

  button 'Change!' do |btn|
    old = @btn
    new_style = old.style.dup
    txt = new_style[:text].next!
    old.parent.before(old) do
      @btn = button txt, new_style
    end
    old.remove #This messes up the click events on Windows.
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

A very old question, but there is a solution.
You didn't mention your shoes color, so i use green.
Green Shoes is based on GTK2, so you can use the methods of GTK2 if you extract the GTK2 object like this.

```
require 'green_shoes'

Shoes.app do
  @btn = button('old text ') {|btn|alert('Hello, World!')}
  button('Change!') {|btn|@btn.real.set_label("new")}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of simulating changing the text of a button by replacing it with a new button with the same action as the old.

The button is first removed from its container (a stack or a flow) and then a new one is added.  This new button will appear at the end of the container, so it may be necessary to have a stack or flow just for this button.

```
# Display 2 buttons, A and B.  Initially button A has text "a".
# Pressing the top button, A, just shows the value of @ch (which is
# the text of the button) on the console.
# Pressing the second button appears to change the text of button A.
# It actually replaces it with a new button with the same action as the old.
Shoes.app do
  def button_a_function
    info("click!  #{@ch}")
  end
  @ch = "a"
  @the_flow = flow do
    para "Button A, whose to be changed"
    @b1 = button @ch do
      button_a_function
    end
  end
  flow do
    para "Button B"
    @b2 = button("Change it") {
      @ch.succ!
      @b1.remove
      @b1 = @the_flow.button (@ch) {
        button_a_function
      }
    }
  end
end
```